# Write to scanf with another program

Tags: linux, shell

I have a program that reads from the standard input stream, `stdin`, via [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) and prints it to `stdout`. I want to send the input via another program. How can I solve this?

Something like:

```
echo hi | ./prog
```

But that does not current work as expected. prog currently looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char buf[200];
scanf("%s",buf);
printf("%s",buf);
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please provide any relevant code to get assistance with this question.

Comment: In what way does it not work as expected?  What did you expect? and what is the actual result?  The program looks valid however meaningless.. what other functionality do you expect?

Comment: I want the program to respond with "hi" but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: you probably didn't compile it....

Answer (score 3):

Since `%s` ignores leading white space and stops at the first following white space, you probably want to include a newline in the printing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[200];
    scanf("%199s", buf);
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

This will read a 'word' of up to 199 characters from standard input and write it to standard output.

Comment: This works fine. The problem is I can not change the code in this case as the origin of the problem is a binary file

Comment: @jarCrack then try "echo hi | ./prog; echo"

Comment: So, you have an executable that is supposed to respond `hi` when given `hi` as input, but it ignores you?  That is going to be tricky to debug.  One thing to look at is the exit status of the program (executable), and see whether it is zero (success) or non-zero (failure).  If it is non-zero, then what you're supplying is presumably not satisfactory to it as input.  If it is zero, you might still have that problem — it is not unknown for programs to exit with a zero status even when they failed — but there's a presumption that it worked.  How do you know what the program's supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

The program worked for me.....

```
$ cat >prog.c
#inlcude <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char buf[200];
  scanf("%s",buf);
  printf("%s",buf);
}
$ make prog
cc     prog.c   -o prog
$ echo hi | ./prog 
hi
```

Comment: Doesn't the prompt appear immediately after the `hi`?

Comment: ... and yes, the prompt does appear after the "hi", which is to be expected as there is no newline printed, im not sure if I can tell if that is what the OP is complaining about...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what happens with the prompt depends on the shell... pretty sure zsh can be configured to check for this issue and not clobber the last line, adding a CR LF itself, and some shells output just a carriage return or cursor move sequence first to ensure they're in the leftmost column.